# 404 not found error for admin page

Tags: magento2, admin, nginx, 404-page

I installed Magento  successfully, but the Admin page gives error: 404 not found. Please suggest a solution for this.

The following is the error:

```
404 Not Found

nginx/1.10.0 (Ubuntu)
```

Comment: where did you get nginx config?

Comment: try siteurl/index.php/admin

Comment: Having custom different ports for secure and unsecured base_url also can be the issue. Mine was:
http://somehost.com:4226/
https://somehost.com:6226/
As result I get 404 when try to access Admin.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/151307)

Answer (score 28):

Please try Below steps

1. Delete `var/cache`  folder
2. Go to database `SELECT * FROM core_config_data WHERE path = 'web/seo/use_rewrites'`  and make it `0`
3. Then enter url in your browser `magento_base_url/index.php/your_admin_url`

try and let me know if you face any issue.

Comment: What does this `web/seo/use_rewrites` value do?

Comment: @Niels  it will remove `index.php` from url if it sets to 1

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala Still i am getting same error where i need to focus?

Comment: @zus please check backend=>frontname in `app/etc/env.php` file

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala I serve magento2.4  using php internal server with command `php -S localhost:8080 -t pub`, I tried your solution, but still get 404 when request http://localhost:8080/index.php/magento2/admin_1ibt8z

Comment: @VidyVideni I am not sure but please check this URL , http://localhost:8080/magento2/index.php/admin_1ibt8z

Answer (score 28):

For Linux edit the file /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

To edit this file use **sudo vi /etc/apache2/apache2.conf command**

```
<Directory /var/www/>
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
     AllowOverride None
     Require all granted
</Directory>
```

**to**

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

After this run command

> sudo service apache2 restart

**IF STILL ADMIN SHOW 404 NOT FOUND, FOLLOW THIS STEP**

1) Add **.htaccess** at root of magento 2

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/.htaccess

2) Now run this command

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade
>
> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
>
> rm -rf var/cache/*
>
> rm -rf var/generation/*

Comment: what are you talking about???? nginx ≠ apache

Comment: Agreed.  The OP references Nginx.  But as I did have the same problem with Apache 2.4, what I found worked was a) `a2dismod rewrite` (even though it was enabled!), then b) restart Apache, then c) `a2enmod rewrite` and then d) restart Apache again.  This solved the problem and it was the second time I encountered this on a new install of Apache.

And clear cache and pray of course :)

Answer (score 9):

Why nobody talk about ?

```
bin/magento info:adminuri
```

This will display your adminuri. More info can be found [here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-adminurl.html#instgde-cli-displayurl).

Answer (score 6):

I also had this issue, it turned out one of my URLs was set to the IP address and not to the domain name so going to the {domain}/admin was returning not found.

Solution was to run

```
php bin/magento config:set web/secure/base_url https://domain.com/
php bin/magento config:set web/unsecure/base_url https://domain.com/
```

Don't forget the trailing slash, it will not work without it
https://alanstorm.com/invalid-base-url-value-must-be-a-url-or-one-of/

Comment: this fix worked for me after migrating an old 2.0.15 installation to 2.2.x.  During the  setup the un-secure url did not have https:// protocol and was the default, the admin url, in the advanced section was configured to use https:// but they BOTH need to be set to be https otherwise page not found issue occurs.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I had too many stores to change and I forgot `web/unsecure/base_url` where the scope_id is 1

Answer (score 5):

Check if `admin/url/custom` is empty and `admin/url/use_custom` is set to 0.

Answer (score 4):

Other possible solution is to check for `.htaccess` file in `root directory` and add if it doesn't exists (https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/.htaccess)

Answer (score 3):

I have also same issue. I updated value for "admin/url/custom" to 0 in core_config_data table and my issue resolved.

Answer (score 2):

Check if the `mod_rewrite` module is enabled in Apache.
To enable mod_rewite module, go to `httpd.conf` file located at `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` and look for `"LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so"`, if it is commented, then uncomment it by removing # at the front.

Comment: The OP was about Nginx - but as I mentioned above to @Prince Patel, the thing that worked for me was: 1. `a2dismod rewrite` 2. `service apache2 restart`  3. `a2enmod rewrite` 4. `service apache2 restart` - seems that disabling and enabling rewrite does the job.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue after server migration by query db & get custom admin url

Actually my env admin path not working for admin login url

**'backend' => [  'frontName' => 'myadmin' ],
http://www.magento.lan/myadmin**  404 erorr

Check Admin Url:

```
bin/magento info:adminuri
```

**Solution:**

**Step1**: First Get Custom admin path

```
SELECT * FROM `core_config_data` where path like "%admin/url/custom_path%";
```

**Step2**: Disable Custom admin Path

Disable from db:

```
UPDATE `core_config_data` SET `value` = '0' WHERE `core_config_data`.`path` LIKE "%admin/url/use_custom_path%";
```

Disable from admin:

AdminLogin==>Store=>Configuration=>Advanced=>Admin=>Admin Base URL=>Use Custom Admin Path:=No

I hope it  will be save time for someone

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help you

`bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` 
 Run this command In your CLI

Comment: Curious, how is this a solution for the admin returning a 404?

Answer (score 1):

Check this for Magento 2.4.3 and Apache 2

sudo subl /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

```
<Directory /var/www/>
 Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
 AllowOverride All
 Require all granted
</Directory>
```

sudo a2enmod rewrite

systemctl restart apache2

In core_config_data change the web/unsecure/base_url to url + pub/

example

http://mylocal.com.co/magento/magento24 to http://mylocal.com.co/magento/magento24/pub/

delete cache of magento

php ./bin/magento cache:flush

[image]

Frontend.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First you have to remove content from `var/cache` and `var/session` folder  ,then change execute this command from commandline/terminal

`bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

Comment: Curious, how is this a solution for the admin returning a 404?

Answer (score 0):

Just try http://127.0.0.1/ instead of http://127.0.0.1 which worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Below is the quick one that I had faced with v2.2.5 and fixed like below.

Go to

```
cd /your-project-root-folder/app/
```

and fire

```
chmod -R 755 etc/
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, as well. For me removing the all var folder by: 
`rm -rf var/` and clearing all browser cache: `Cmd+Shift+Delete` or `Command-Shift-Delete` for mac, did the trick.

I hope it will help someone!

Answer (score 0):

go check you `/app/etc/env.php` file `backend[front_name => admin_kjdfk]`. and use this, like `base_url/admin_kjdfk`