# Magento 2 : Admin url 404 not found

Tags: magento2, php, database, apache, apache2

I know there are many answers for this i tried all and not able to do it on my server hosted with godaddy magento latest version

I tried this

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

[404 not found error for admin page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/133679/404-not-found-error-for-admin-page)

didn't work out

then

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

rm -rf var/cache/*

rm -rf var/generation/*
```

this dint work out

added httaccess to my root directory

https://github.com/emizentech/magento2/blob/master/.htaccess.sample

though it was not there still dint work out
home page works fine as expected with no erros on it

but admin page says 404 error

**domain.com/admin**

```
Not Found
The requested URL /admin was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at 192.169.143.135 Port 80
```

If I added `domain.com/index.php/admin`

```
Not Found
The requested URL /admin/admin/index/index/key/be1e5947f83b71x354749eds3ba0aa7321a8a8d659aca49cc8a00fb4de1cc57ab956f/ was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at 192.169.143.135 Port 80
```

I enabled developer mode to

```
 main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http://192.169.143.135/index.php/admin/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["interception","CONFIG"],"mode":"matchingTag"}} []
```

[image]

Comment: have you checked your admin front name in `env.php`

Comment: 'backend' => [
    'frontName' => 'admin'
  ],
it is same

Comment: do you have multistore?

Comment: no it is just a single store site newly installed on this server

Comment: Is this `http://192.169.143.135/index.php` OR `http://192.169.143.135/` URL working?

Comment: i did a re install here again same problem
admin :
http://cmcollective.net/magento/admin_3beh8v/

site
http://cmcollective.net/magento/

Comment: check your apache and htaccess configurations. it is removing 'index.php'  from URL otherwise working fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78369/discussion-between-shaik-and-kunj).

Comment: there is no httaccess in root directory

Comment: @kunj https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/89634/after-successful-installation-admin-url-is-returning-a-404

fineally this solved my problem

Comment: Great, congratulations, please add this in answer with proper format and accept your answer, so it will help to others, I really happy to help you.

Comment: @kunj done ! :) thanks for your support much appreciated

Answer (score 5):

Please try Below steps

- Delete var/cache folder
- Go to database SELECT * FROM core_config_data WHERE path = 'web/seo/use_rewrites' and make it 0
- Then enter url in your browser magento_base_url/index.php/your_admin_url

try and let me know if you face any issue.

Comment: i did check the updated image no effects

Comment: Can you check url rewrites enable or disable. if enable than you can disable after cache flush and check.

Comment: this one worked for me , thank you

Answer (score 5):

Fileally After Rebuilding Server again

installing php 7.1 mysql marine

apache2

got the solution

Source : [After successful installation, admin URL is returning a 404?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/89634/after-successful-installation-admin-url-is-returning-a-404)

I was also facing the same problem. My frontend's css is not loading as well as admin panel was giving 404 error page. The solution of both the problem in ubuntu is enable Apache server rewrites:

1. Go to your terminal and run this command:

   > sudo gedit /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

   And change:

   ```
   <Directory /var/www/>
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride none
   Require all granted
   ```

   To

   ```
   <Directory /var/www/>
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride All
   Require all granted
   ```

   change only `AllowOverride` `none` to `All`
2. Go to your terminal and run command:

   > sudo a2enmod rewrite
   >
   > sudo service apache2 restart
3. Then give the permission to your `var`, `pub` and `app/etc`. and then go to your admin and frontend it works properly.

Answer (score 1):

Change Admin Path and try again:

It is not recommended to change it directly from `app/etc/env.php`, always prefer the CLI:

```
php bin/magento setup:config:set --backend-frontname="admin_url"
```

Comment: `php bin/magento setup:config:set --backend-frontname="admin"` tried no effect

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had accidentally set a store as the default in the control panel:

[image]

In core_config_data:

layout_switcher/general/default_theme was set to 'interiors'

Whenever I tried to access the admin area, I got the template for interiors and a 404. To fix I set:

layout_switcher/general/default_theme back to 'base'

I then ran:

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```