# admin url show the page is not working in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, php

My front is working fine and  **admin url:admin_rillmark** redirect to the following url

```
http://127.0.0.1/test11/admin_rillmark/admin/auth/login/key/9a93d07026bee02246470be7e230d6edc0bd5f8bb0b20b749794ae272c7c9c8a/
```

Gives the error page is not working.

Comment: can you check this link : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/228430/magento-2-admin-url-404-not-found/228439#228439

Comment: Can you please check at firefox . might be you have issue in google chorme

Comment: I have change the SELECT * FROM core_config_data WHERE path = 'web/seo/use_rewrites' and make it 0 .Now my url :http://127.0.0.1/test11/index.php/admin_rillmark/admin/index/denied/key/3629653e3d3abcbbc416b635141d0bc827c619a15c1a4c64c2960355bc7435bf/  still give error page is not working.

Comment: Show log file errors that will help......

Answer (score 1):

There could be multiple reasons behind that...

Try to show some log... 
meanwhile run these command..

`php bin/magento setup:upgrade
 php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f 
 php bin/magento indexer:reindex
 php bin/magento cache:flush`

then retry...

Answer (score 0):

Run this command in Magento directory

```
composer upgrade
```

Magento will start running chears

Answer (score 0):

Below commands will figure out the problems

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile 
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f 
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Enjoy!!!