# Admin URL showing 404 Not found in Magento2.2.6

Tags: admin, magento2.2.6

I have installed fresh Magento2.2.6.

When I open its admin URL using

> `http://127.0.0.1/magento226/admin`

or

> `http://127.0.0.1/magento226/index.php/admin`,

it is redirected to

> http://127.0.0.1/magento226/admin/admin/index/index/key/79f05d66e460a56c70ff504e6f04c512a60322a973ddf048899336fc64d9f9f1/

What's wrong there ?

Comment: Please add .htaccess file.

Comment: its there already

Comment: Also added in pub?

Comment: yes..there too.

Comment: Frontend working or not ?

Comment: yes its working

Comment: Please check this url.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/133679/404-not-found-error-for-admin-page

Comment: Bingooo...`web/seo/use_rewrites = 0` is hero. thanks @PayalPatel for help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85187/discussion-between-payal-patel-and-shashank-kumrawat).