# Magento 2.4.2 Not working after fresh installation

Tags: magento2, installation, magento2.4.2

I installed Magento 2.4.2 in my local. Installed Apache2, composer 2, MySQL 8 and enabled extensions. Installed M2.4.2, after running all commands, it is showing 404 both frontend and admin. I checked the below links too. But not working...

Reference links:

1. [Magento 2: Static files are present but shows 404](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/205471/magento-2-static-files-are-present-but-shows-404)
2. [404 not found error for admin page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/133679/404-not-found-error-for-admin-page/133680)

Answer (score 0):

Try to run these commands.

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
sudo chmod -R 777 var/ generated/ pub/
```

Comment: Tried all these commands.

Comment: Confirm you do this things : /etc/apache2/apache2.conf.

Answer (score 0):

I missed configuring the virtual host. Followed [this tutorial](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/245741/35778), After that it is working.